# How to scale the Bar chart values beyond 100 in Google Image URL chart

Tags: node.js, charts, google-visualization, data-visualization, visualization

I am using the Google image chart API to create a Bar chart image URL dynamically, to embed the URL into the Node.js Bot card.

The parameters passed to create the image bar chart URL is as follows:

```
cht=bvg
chxt=x,y

chs=100x100
chd=t:310,260
chl=TX
    WA
chco=00FF00
    3399FF
chm=N,000000,0,,10
chtt=Analysis
```

The generated bar chart URL is shown below:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxt=x,y&chs=100x100&chd=t:310,260&chl=TX|WA&chco=00FF00|3399FF&chm=N,000000,0,,10&chtt=Analysis
```

The segment `chd=t:310,260` is displayed in the bar chart URL as 100, 100 instead of 310, 260

**How to scale the Bar chart to show the Bars above 100 and display their values beyond 100?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chds` will change the axis scale

allow values from `0` to `400` = `chds=0,400`

`chxr` to change the axis range / labels

change y-axis axis range from `0` to `400` and step by `100`

`chxr=1,0,400,100`

[image]

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxt=x,y&chs=100x100&chd=t:310,260&chds=0,400&chxr=1,0,400,100&chl=TX|WA&chco=00FF00|3399FF&chm=N,000000,0,,10&chtt=Analysis
```